# How to disconnect from rabbitmq after each test?

Tags: spring, amqp, spring-test, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have integrated with rabbitmq in a spring application. There are two SpringRunner tests which assert on whether the amqp receiver receives a message. The tests connect to a rabbitmq broker running in a separate process.

The problem is that the application context loads on first test and registers a consumer to the queue, but does not disconnect after the test completes.

When the second test runs, the application context for it also registers a consumer, but any messages sent to the exchange as a part of the second test still go to the consumer registered by application context from the first test.

Both the tests run sequentially.

Is there a way to kill the first context completely before the second test starts so that there is just one consumer at a time ? Or any other way to solve the problem ?
Thank you

Tried @DirtiesContext before test did not help

Comment: `@DirtiesContext` should work if you are using a Spring test context; edit the question to show your tests and configuration.

Comment: I think you can use `@After` or `@AfterTest` for this purpose

Answer (score 2):

Well, to be honest a `@DirtiesContext` on all the test classes level, alongside with the `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`, is the way to.

The `ListenerContainer` is an active component which starts its own threads, so even when you are done with your test, it doesn't mean that background thread is stopped. For this purpose you indeed have to use a `@DirtiesContext` on every test class to ensure that all the application contexts are closed after finishing tests. It ensures that those listener containers are stopped as well.

It is just not enough to place a `@DirtiesContext` on your one test class, because there is no guarantee in which order they are going to be called. So, present it as much as possible on your test classes to avoid this or similar race conditions.